# How do I get the output to be displayed in a JList Client?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Client Side:

```
public List<String> playlist()
{
    try
        {
         InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_NAME); 
         Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, DEST_PORT);

         BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()) );

         String rLine; 
         DefaultListModel  listModel = new DefaultListModel();

         String reply = BR.readLine();

         System.out.println("ddddddd");

         while((rLine = BR.readLine()) != null)   
         {
             System.out.println("aaaaa");
             listModel.addElement(rLine); 
             System.out.println(rLine); 
             System.out.println("dhhhhh");
         }
             PlayList.setModel(listModel);
         }
             catch(Exception e) {}`enter code here`
     }
```

Server Side:

```
public class MediaServer {    
   try {

       ServerSocket svrSocket = new ServerSocket(DEST_PORT); 

       while(true){
       System.out.println("waiting for clients...");
       Socket ClientSocket = svrSocket.accept();


       DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
       BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));

       InetAddress clientIP = ClientSocket.getInetAddress(); 


       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
       String folder = "mySongs"; 
       System.out.println(workingDirectory);

       String absolutePath = workingDirectory + File.separator + folder;  

       System.out.println(absolutePath);

       File mediaFolder = new File(folder);


       if(mediaFolder.isDirectory())
       {

           File [] playList = mediaFolder.listFiles(); 

           if(playList != null)
           {
               for(int i = 0; i < playList.length; i++)
               {
                   if(!playList[i].isDirectory())
                   {
                       String fileNames = playList[i].getName();
                       out.writeUTF(fileNames);
                       System.out.print(i + fileNames);
                   }

               }

           }
       } else { 
                       // System.out.println("No Music Folder Exists");
                   }



       //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream();
   //  String songRequest = bis.readLine();


   }



   }
   catch(Exception e) { 


   }
}
```

Comment: `readLine` will wait until a new line character appears in your stream, it doesn't appear that you're writing a new line character at the server end

Comment: Wow!!!! Thanks a lot. The little things really do matter.